# Bash: How to execute paths

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab-ci, jobs, cicd

I have job in my gitlab-cicd.yml file:

```
unit_test:
  stage: test
  image: $MAVEN_IMAGE
  script:
    - *tests_variables_export
    - mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean test
    - cat ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/rest-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
    - cat ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/soap-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'code coverage'
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/soap-service/target/surefire-reports/
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/rest-service/target/surefire-reports/
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/soap-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/rest-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
```

And I want to change it to this one:

```
unit_test:
  stage: test
  image: $MAVEN_IMAGE
  script:
    - *tests_variables_export
    - mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean test
    - cat ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/rest-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
    - cat ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/soap-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'code coverage'
    paths:
      - *resolve_paths
```

I try to use this bash script:

```
.resolve_paths: &resolve_paths |-
  if [ "${MODULE_FIRST}" != "UNKNOWN" ]; then
    echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${MODULE_FIRST}/target/surefire-reports/"
    echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${MODULE_FIRST}/target/site/jacoco/index.html"
  fi
  if [ "${MODULE_SECOND}" != "UNKNOWN" ]; then
    echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${MODULE_SECOND}/target/surefire-reports/"
    echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${MODULE_SECOND}/target/site/jacoco/index.html"
  fi
```

And right now I'm getting this error in pipeline:

`WARNING: if [ "rest-service" != "UNKNOWN" ]; then\n  echo "- /builds/minv/common/testcommons/taf-api-support/rest-service/target/surefire-reports/"\n  echo "- /builds/minv/common/testcommons/taf-api-support/rest-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html"\nfi\nif [ "soap-service" != "UNKNOWN" ]; then\n  echo "- /builds/minv/common/testcommons/taf-api-support/soap-service/target/surefire-reports/"\n  echo "- /builds/minv/common/testcommons/taf-api-support/soap-service/target/site/jacoco/index.html"\nfi: no matching files  ERROR: No files to upload`

Comment: @Socowi I edited as you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I execute [sic] paths using bash script like this?

No, scripts cannot alter the current YAML, particularly not if you specify the script (which is just a string) in a place where it is interpreted as a path.

You could [trigger a dynamically generated YAML](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines):

```
generate:
  stage: build
  script:
    - |
      exec > generated.yml
      echo ".resolve_paths: &resolve_paths"
      for module in "${MODULE_FIRST}" "${MODULE_SECOND}"; do
        [[ "$module" = UNKNOWN ]] && continue
          echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${module}/target/surefire-reports/"
          echo "- ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${module}/target/site/jacoco/index.html"
      done
      sed '1,/^\.\.\. *$/d' "${CI_CONFIG_PATH}"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated.yml

run:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated.yml
        job: generate

...

# Start of actual CI. When this runs, there will be an
# auto-generated job `.resolve_paths: &resolve_paths`.
# Put the rest of your CI (e.g. `unit_test:`) here.
```

But there are so many extensions in GitLab's YAML that you likely will find a tremendously better solution, which depends on what you plan to do with `.resolve_paths`. Maybe have a look at

- [`artifacts:exclude`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexclude)
- additional jobs with [`rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)